# Excel drop down list that only changes the color of the cell but not the text in the column

Tags: excel

I have a dropdown list of colours.
i want to mention dates in the column yet have a dropdown list of colors and on selecting a color i don't want the dropdown to over write the date or any text i enter in the column

in short When selecting the color from the drop down list it should change the cell color only and not the data within.

Comment: It will definitely change text as you are selecting different text in different type. Otherwise you have to use `VBA` macro.

Comment: well i dont mind using VBA coding but what the coding will be